# SetInterval on functions of an object from within the object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create an object that will work on a `<div>` by replacing it's inner HTML periodically. I'm stumped with the part 'periodically', though. This is what I'm trying to do (the relevant parts of the code, I'm omitting unrelevant declarations etc.):

```
function LedDisplay() {
    this.initialize() {
        window.setInterval(this.redraw, 200);
    };

    this.redraw = function() {
        this.shiftDisplayMatrix();
        $('#' + this.name).html(this.createSvg());
    };

    this.shiftDisplayMatrix = function() {
        var firstRow = this.displayMatrix[0];
        this.displayMatrix.splice(0, 1);
        this.displayMatrix.push(firstRow);
    };
};
```

This results in the following - `this.shiftDisplayMatrix is not a function`. I believe this is because `redraw` is called in the global context and there's no `this.shiftDisplayMatrix` there. What I cannot seem to find is how to achieve what I want.

Or perhaps what I'm trying to do is an antipattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, since the context that called `this.shiftDisplayMatrix` is no longer the object itself, it no longer has access to the function. What you can try doing is

```
function LedDisplay() {
    var self = this;
    ....
}
```

and then call `self.shiftDisplayMatrix`, where we use self to save the context of the LedDisplay object.